# Does the google maps sdk for iOS allow caching for offline use?

Tags: google-maps, ios6, offline, google-maps-sdk-ios

Does the google maps sdk for iOS allow caching for offline use?
Just like the Google Maps app now allow offline interaction, I was thinking if it also aplied to apps created with the latest sdk.

Note: I've been around StackOverflow for sometime now that I know questions *must* be code related, but since the official page's discussion section forward me here with the tag [google-maps-sdk-ios], well.. here I am and I apologize if it shouldn't be this way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of SDK 1.8.1, there is no direct support for this for Google Maps.

It is however possible to use a custom tile overlay, which could load tiles from a downloaded cache. It's against the SDK T&C to download Google Map tiles, but you could provide your own tiles from another provider, e.g. OpenStreetMap.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Could you however provide any link to official docs that say, at least, the first bit of your answer? that's because I am not working with it at the moment, and am not able to test it, and I wanted to mark this one as answered. Thank you

Comment: There is no mention in the SDK documentation about caching maps offline, and the SDK requires a network connection to display Google Maps, which is why I say there is not support for this.

Comment: well.. ok then! makes sense :) thks